# Use WPF expander in Winforms with more than one control

Tags: c#, winforms, wpf-controls

My problem is that I want to use WPF expander object to host some winforms control. And the position that I'm going to use this is in my application's setting form. But, what I couldn't find is to add more than one control to it.

After a lot of searching for solution to my problem I just found this simple code that only add one control to the WPF expander object (I require more than one control to be added):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Controls.Expander expander = new System.Windows.Controls.Expander();
        expander.Header = "Sample";
        WPFHost = new ElementHost();
        WPFHost.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        WindowsFormsHost host = new WindowsFormsHost();
        host.Child = new DateTimePicker();

        expander.Content = host;
        WPFHost.Child = expander;
        this.Controls.Add(WPFHost);
    }
```

In this code the expander only hosts one control.

How should I customize it to host more than one control ?
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a System.Windows.Forms.Panel as a container will help:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.Expander expander = new System.Windows.Controls.Expander();
    System.Windows.Controls.Grid grid = new System.Windows.Controls.Grid();
    expander.Header = "Sample";
    ElementHost WPFHost = new ElementHost();
    WPFHost.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    Panel panel1 = new Panel();
    DateTimePicker dtPicker1 = new DateTimePicker();
    Label label1 = new Label();


    // Initialize the Label and TextBox controls.
    label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 16);
    label1.Text = "Select a date:";
    label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 16);
    dtPicker1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 32);
    dtPicker1.Text = "";
    dtPicker1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 20);

    // Add the Panel control to the form. 
    this.Controls.Add(panel1);
    // Add the Label and TextBox controls to the Panel.
    panel1.Controls.Add(label1);
    panel1.Controls.Add(dtPicker1);


    WindowsFormsHost host = new WindowsFormsHost();
    host.Child = panel1;


    expander.Content = host;
    WPFHost.Child = expander;
    this.Controls.Add(WPFHost);

}
```